# Wordpress not working when using Apache virtual hosts

Tags: wordpress, virtualhost

I currently use virtual hosts on my computer so that I can manage multiple sites on my computer.

Currently, I use **c:/vhosts/php** (default localhost) for regular PHP development, **c:/vhosts/BTS** for Wordpress, and **c:/vhosts/cake** for CakePHP development. (see below).

Now when I launch my WAMPP and go to http://BTS, it loads the index page but nothing else loads fine.  When trying to click on the links, it links to http://localhost/xxxxx instead of http://BTS/xxxxx.  What am I missing here?  I don't want the server to access localhost since I'm using localhost for other projects.  Please help.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot c:/vhosts/php
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot c:/vhosts/BTS
ServerName BTS
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot c:/vhosts/cake
ServerName cake
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Presumably you have hosts entries that resolve 'bts' and 'cake' to 127.0.0.1, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into your MySQL database (thru phpmyadmin or whatever) and look for the following fields

In the wp_options table, change

```
siteurl
home
```

To http://BTS instead of localhost.

This will update all your links in wordpress.

Comment: Right! Why didn't I think of that.  Thanks Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Wordpress what domain it is sitting on.

Login to your Admin CP, it's in settings somewhere

Comment: it won't even let me log into Admin CP on my computer

Answer (score 0):

I think is in wordpress options in settings in general, then change in WordPress Address (URL) and in Site Address (URL), both need to be the same:
[This is my configure, but you can change it with BTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzWp1.png)

And check if it's right in mysql the configure with
select option_name, option_value from wp_options where option_name = 'siteurl';