# MAMP, Apache, Wordpress and the case of the mysterious port number

Tags: apache, wordpress, mamp, virtualhost, hosts

I'm developing a few sites with Wordpress on a local server. I have my MAMP (2.0.1) running with the default port numbers for Apache and MySQL on Lion (10.7.2). It's been working quite well until I recently encountered a perplexing problem.

One site in particular has undergone a few internal domain/vhost changes (this is how I came to the conclusion of using the default port numbers re:my own Wordpress development) which are referenced in my `/etc/hosts` file and also in my MAMP apache `httpd.conf` VirtualHosts section. Now when I visit this particular development domain defined in the hosts and `httpd.conf` vhost, it gives me a browser error stating that it couldn't establish a connection to `dev.example.com:8888` (the Wordpress index.php and htaccess files are in the folder index). I'm a bit annoyed and confused as I've changed the MAMP ports to the default, yet this references the 8888 default MAMP apache port only on the domain index and doesn't want to sway its course even if I visit `dev.example.com:80`. I can access files and folders within the domain by specifically typing them in, but visiting the domain index as it is gives me this error with the default port number. I have no idea why that is and haven't been able to find a solution via the internet.

Some search results have mentioned incorrect line formats in the `hosts` and `httpd.conf` files, but mine are all Unix LF based so that solution hasn't made a difference. I've removed Wordpress from the domain's folder structure and tried again but it still gives me the same error. On another domain I'm using with Wordpress it works fine; the folders are set up exactly the same way, as are the entries in the `hosts` and the `httpd.conf` files. I get no apache errors when I visit the particular erroring domain as well. I'm just a bit stumped on the whole thing.

Hosts entry:

```
127.0.0.1     dev.example.com
```

Vhost entry:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dev.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/Sites/example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Wordpress config:

```
sql.wp_options.siteurl = http://dev.example.com/wp
sql.wp_options.home    = http://dev.example.com/
```

Comment: Any luck working this out?  I'm having a similAr problem with WP and port 8888.

Comment: have you seen the wp_options table in the mysql database? in the option named  siteurl stores the path to your wordpress. maybe it still have the http://dev.example.com:8888/ as your sitename

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress not working when using Apache virtual hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778266/wordpress-not-working-when-using-apache-virtual-hosts)